# How to do flat array of elements in spyne?

Tags: python, soap, spyne

How does one write a request handler for Spyne that handles a SOAP request like this:

```
<getUsers>
  <users>
    <username>foo</username>
    <username>bar</username>
    ...
  </users>
</getUsers>
```

I have tried this:

```
@rpc(Array(Unicode.customize(type_name='username'), min_occurs=1, nillable=False))
def getUsers(ctx, users):
    stuff
```

But it yields a schema like such:

```
  <xs:complexType name="getUsers">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="users" type="tns:stringArray"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="stringArray">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="string" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

How do I change the element name `string` into `username`? And preferably also `stringArray` into something more meaningful? Is my approach completely wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2.10:

```
SomeArrayType = Array(Unicode, min_occurs=1, 
                               nillable=False, type_name='SomeArrayType')
SomeArrayType._type_info['username'] = SomeArrayType._type_info['string']
del SomeArrayType._type_info['string']

@rpc(SomeArrayType)
def some_call(ctx, some_array):
    # (...)
```

2.11:

```
from spyne import Mandatory as M
SomeArrayType = M(Array(Unicode, type_name='SomeArrayType',
                                                member_name='username'))

@rpc(SomeArrayType)
def some_call(ctx, some_array):
    # (...)
```

Also, if you need the array to be non empty, you also need Unicode(min_len=1, min_occurs=1, nillable=False) inside the Array. i.e.:

```
SomeArrayType = M(Array(M(Unicode), type_name='SomeArrayType',
                                                member_name='username'))
```

Comment: 2.11 is to be released towards beginning of June